# python django name conventions

Tags: python, django, class, naming-conventions

the naming convention for `ForeignKey` is to name with the lowercase version of the connected `model`, the following is taken from the docs:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    # ...

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass
```

but I have the following models:

```
class Work(models.model):
    class = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    #...

class Class(models.model):
    #...
    pass
```

As we know, this will raise an error because we cannot set a variable to `class` because it is built into python.

## Question:

**will not following the naming conventions actually be a problem in the SQL database creation?**

for example:

```
class Work(models.model):
    cls = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    #...

class Class(models.model):
    #...
    pass
```

**will having a different ForeignKey name mess up the SQL table and database creation?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely want to stay away from reserved words such as Class, List, String, etc.  Whether it will mess up your database or not, I'm not sure (try it and see!) but it's definitely a bad idea.  If it's not a sql problem, it will mess up something somewhere eventually.

I see 'klass' a lot, if you feel like the word class is absolutely necessary.  'Course', perhaps?

Comment: `cls` is a common contraction too

Comment: Okay this is true, please look at my edit in the question part and answer that please. I am just curious on that end

Comment: I would change the class name from 'Class' to something else as well, for the same reasons.  However, `foo = models.ForeignKey(bar)`, in general, is fine (although possibly more confusing than necessary).